# How to setup a simple color scheme via CSS Root Variables?

Tags: javascript, html, css, colors

I would like to set the color scheme based on simple CSS root variables.
The JavaScript does not work: it does not see/set the root variables when one of the options are clicked. What have I overlooked to make this simple color scheme work?

```js
const setTheme = theme => document.documentElement.className = theme;
document.getElementById('themeoptions').addEventListener('change', function() {
    setTheme(this.value);
});
```

```css
#themeoptions p{ /* User Interface */
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: underline;
}#themeoptions p:hover{cursor: pointer}


:root.light {
  --bgr: #ddc;
  --txt: #456;
}
:root.dark {
  --bgr: #222;
  --txt: #844;
}
:root.blue {
  --bgr: #046;
  --txt: #dde;
}


body {
  background-color: var(--bgr);
  color: var(--txt);
}
```

```html
<div id="themeoptions">
    <p value="light">Light</p>
    <p value="dark">Dark</p>
    <p value="blue">Blue</p>
</div>

<h1>Click on a theme to change the color scheme!</h1>
```

Comment: What change event do you think gets triggered here?

Comment: Should `'change'` be `'click'` ? But then still it does not work. This is a tough one for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are three problems to address in your JavaScript code:

1. The `value` property on an element does not refer to the attribute that you have named `value` on your paragraph elements. To access the value of this property, you'll need to use [`Element.getAttribute()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute).
2. `this` in your event listener callback function does not refer to the target element of the event. To access the target element, you'll need to use [`Event.target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target).
3. The event that you want to listen for is most likely the [`click` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/click_event) (not the `change` event).

```js
const setTheme = theme => document.documentElement.className = theme;
document.getElementById('themeoptions').addEventListener('click', ({target}) => {
  setTheme(target.getAttribute('value'));
});
```

```css
#themeoptions p{ /* User Interface */
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: underline;
}#themeoptions p:hover{cursor: pointer}


:root.light {
  --bgr: #ddc;
  --txt: #456;
}
:root.dark {
  --bgr: #222;
  --txt: #844;
}
:root.blue {
  --bgr: #046;
  --txt: #dde;
}


body {
  background-color: var(--bgr);
  color: var(--txt);
}
```

```html
<div id="themeoptions">
    <p value="light">Light</p>
    <p value="dark">Dark</p>
    <p value="blue">Blue</p>
</div>

<h1>Click on a theme to change the color scheme!</h1>
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for the clarity of the three problems. I will now investigate them one by one. And thank you for the working solution!

Comment: I also figured that by adding `:root,` in the beginning of the desired default color scheme, that scheme will be loaded by default, if no scheme is set yet.

Comment: I wonder, would it be possible to have a theme called `:root.default {}` in the CSS, and have the Javascript code to load the `"default"` theme if nothing is set yet?

Comment: @Såm You are always welcome to [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) if you have one.

Comment: Roger that, I will :)

Comment: JSLint gives a warning/error on this code. `[JSLint was unable to finish] Wrap the parameter before '=>' in parens.` Can this be safely ignored?

Comment: @Såm You haven't provided enough information for me to answer your question (it's also not related to this Stack Overflow question). (1) You might want to read up on [arrow function expression syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#syntax). (2) And, again, instead of asking new questions in comments, please ask them by [opening a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) if you can't find the answer. This allows everyone to benefit from the format of the website. Good luck!

Comment: Sorry I thought asking a question _below and about_ the current answer, was and is helpful for the community and for the answer itself. I apparently do not know exactly when to ask a competely new question and when to add a question on the existing page, sothat the community would find the related things more easily. Let me ask in a different way: When would you advise not to ask a new question and rather ask something directly under the given answer? Thanks.

Comment: @Såm Generally, you shouldn't ask follow up questions at all in comments except to get clarity from another commenter/answerer if what they posted wasn't clear in some way: any details about your inquiry should go in the content of your question post. Re: [your question above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72411549/how-to-setup-a-simple-color-scheme-via-css-root-variables/72411621?noredirect=1#comment127921614_72411621): it's about a linter diagnostic for a program called "JSLint", which is completely unrelated to the content in your posted question, so it should be a separate question.

Comment: Stack Overflow has a great section on [asking questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) with tons of information. If you would like a specific article to get started, the titled [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) is a great entrypoint.